# Remove HTML tags from description and short-description while Exporting Products in Magento

Tags: magento2, product-description

I need to remove HTML tags from product description and short-description while exporting the products using the Magento default Import-Export module.

current CSV description column

```
<ul>
    <li>Foam-padded adjustable shoulder straps.</li>
    <li>900D polyester.</li>
    <li>Oversized zippers.</li>
    <li>Locker loop.</li>
</ul>
```

description column I want in CSV

```
Foam-padded adjustable shoulder straps.
900D polyester.
Oversized zippers.
Locker loop.
```

Answer (score 1):

With Magento 2, to remove HTML tags :

**In a Block or .phtml file**

Just use `$this->stripTags($html)`.

**In a Controller**

```php
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager
     */
    protected $filterManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->filterManager = $filterManager;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $html = "<ul>
                    <li>Foam-padded adjustable shoulder straps.</li>
                    <li>900D polyester.</li>
                    <li>Oversized zippers.</li>
                    <li>Locker loop.</li>
                </ul>";

        // Change thoses 2 variables if needed
        $allowableTags = null;
        $allowHtmlEntities = false;

        // Params are optionnal. If you use défault values you can remove it.
        $params = ['allowableTags' => $allowableTags, 'escape' => $allowHtmlEntities];

        $strWithoutHtml = $this->filterManager->stripTags($html, $params);

        die($strWithoutHtml); // Foam-padded adjustable shoulder straps. 900D polyester. Oversized zippers. Locker loop.
    }
```

Comment: The $this->stripTags($html) function is operating smoothly within the .phtml file.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

This isn't related to magento but php.

Check `strip_tags()` function. She takes a string as a parameter and remove all tags from it.

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
//Print Test paragraph. Other text
```